# f is an entire function, show that it is a constant function using Liouville theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

let f be an entire function such that $|f(z) + e^z| > |e^zf(z)|$ for all z in C.
Show that f is a constant function.

Suggestion is to use Liouville's theorem then show that f is actually the constant zero function. But don't even know how to start? I'm sure I need to form a g(z) but not sure what my g should be.

Comment: Hint: Prove it on all bounded Balls around $0$.

Comment: You have an inequality $\lvert h(z)\rvert > \lvert g(z)\rvert$ for all $z$, so what would be a natural candidate to throw Liouville's theorem against?

Answer (score 1):

$g(z) = (e^zf(z))/(f(z) + e^z)$ and we know $|g(z)| < 1$, entire and bounded implies constant. From it try to deduce this constant is 0 and which will imply in eventuality that $f(z) \equiv 0$.

Comment: at some point i'll get $f(z) = (ke^z)/(e^z-k)$ and there's no way to determine that |f(z)| is constant cause there's no upper bound on e^z?

Comment: I said get k = 0

Comment: That is, g(z) = k.

Comment: I see your problem now.  Notice that this $f$ that you get is not entire unless $k=0$.